# Could dialogflow auto estimate the locations distance

Tags: dialogflow-es

If I have a list of locations for my events. If user have a question which event is nearest to his location, can the chatbot answer it ?

I know that dialogflow could know the distance (or range) for date-time, for example you input your opening hour of your shop then user can ask "are you opening now" and chatbot can answer precisely.

So I think if they can do it for time, then they can also do for space? They could do similar thing to locations ?

Comment: no, you Dialogflow does not do that automatically if you need to get nearest place to your location you can use google map service, or can write your own logic to get nearest place with geo coordinates

Comment: dialogflow and google map both come from google, why don't they just integrate them too as they do for google calendar ... Is there an example anyone did it before for chat bot ?

Comment: you have to do it with your logic, or you can share if you have tried, i don't think anyone would directly share there code like this.